# How to properly test if selected theme is light mode or dark mode

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, android-instrumentation

I am new to testing and trying to test this in my fragment:

When user clicks an icon, check the selected theme first (using live data).

- If the selected theme is light, change to dark mode and assert that it is dark mode:
- Else, if the selected theme is dark, change to light mode and assert that it is light mode:

**HomeFragmentTest.kt**

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@UninstallModules(StorageModule::class)
class HomeFragmentTest{

@get:Rule(order = 0)
var hiltAndroidRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@get:Rule(order = 1)
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Inject
lateinit var dataStorage: DataStorage

@Before
fun setUp(){
    hiltAndroidRule.inject()
}

private lateinit var storageViewModel: StorageViewModel
private var selectedTheme: String? = null

@Test
fun testThatThemeIsChangedWhenClicked(){
    storageViewModel = StorageViewModel(dataStorage)
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<HomeFragment> {
       selectedTheme = storageViewModel.selectedTheme.getOrAwaitValue()
    }

    onView(withId(R.id.ic_theme_mode)).perform(click())

    if (selectedTheme == "light"){
        runOnUiThread {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            storageViewModel.changeSelectedTheme("dark")
        }
        assertThat(selectedTheme).isEqualTo("dark")
    }

    else if (selectedTheme == "dark"){
        runOnUiThread {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            storageViewModel.changeSelectedTheme("light")
        }
        assertThat(selectedTheme).isEqualTo("light")
    }
 }
}
```

**StorageViewModel.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class StorageViewModel @Inject constructor(private val dataStorage: DataStorage) 
: ViewModel()  {

val selectedTheme = dataStorage.selectedTheme().asLiveData()
fun changeSelectedTheme(theme: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        dataStorage.setSelectedTheme(theme)
    }
 }
}
```

It seems that for some reasons, "**storageViewModel.changeSelectedTheme("dark")**" doesn't work.

The tests fails, with the error:

> **expected: dark but was : light  at HomeFragmentTest.testThatThemeIsChangedWhenClicked(HomeFragmentTest.kt:70)**

When I run again, I get:

> **expected: light but was : dark  at HomeFragmentTest.testThatThemeIsChangedWhenClicked(HomeFragmentTest.kt:76)**

Answer (score 0):

`runOnUiThread` posts a runnable to the event queue of the main thread, and the code gets executed later - so your check happens before the theme is actually changed. (Unless you're already on the main thread, in which case you wouldn't need `runOnUiThread` in the first place)

You might want to use the [`UiThreadTest` annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/annotation/UiThreadTest) so the whole test runs on the main thread, then you don't need to worry about async handling

Comment: I got - Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main), when I used @UiThreadTest annotation on the test. Error came from the launchFragmentInHiltContainer<HomeFragment> {} line